# Receiving error page when publishing new view pages MVC 5 to IIS 8.5 , works fine debugging on local

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, iis-8

Server Error in '' Application. After turning off customErrors.
Receiving the below on two new view pages, i created the views, they work fine when debugging on my local. 
The views are cshtml, from iEnumerable models, returning a toList()
using currentURL Request.URL.AbsoluteURi in the view which might be the problem?
I've denied annonymous authentication, enabled windows auth.

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command) +2076283
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async) +328
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +130
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +98
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +202
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +104
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +505
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +37

[EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +126
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +1047
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +469
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() +205
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +238
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +349
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption) +188
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad() +449
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty(TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject) +131
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__2(TProxy proxy, TItem item) +151
   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Milestone_A196562B8A8F9C6DAB6533FEB9BCA439C46C7CA6A6A60E91A85439617B2A923F.get_Initiative() +39
   WAD_MP.Controllers.MilestonesController.List(Nullable`1 id) +979
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +145
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +209
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +386
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +186
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +399
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing the if statement query to ToList()

rather than just converting toList at end of controller, i had to make sure the if statements were using toList() as well